# Grouping nodes inside an XML based on the value of their attributes using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am quite new with XSL and in need of some help. I have an XML file that need to be transformed as follows: 
The exisitng file:

```
<root>
    <highernode> 
        <highernodename>Name1</highernodename>
        <highernodeId>Id1</highernodeId>
            <node name="node1">
                <somechild child-id="1"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node2">
                <somechild child-id="2"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node3">
                <somechild child-id="1"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node4">
                <somechild child-id="2"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node5">
                <somechild child-id="3"/>
            </node>
    </highernode>

    <highernode>
        <highernodename>Name2</highernodename>
        <highernodeId>Id2</highernodeId>
            <node name="node1">
                <somechild child-id="1"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node2">
                <somechild child-id="5"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node3">
                <somechild child-id="5"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node6">
                <somechild child-id="4"/>
            </node>
            <node name="node5">
                <somechild child-id="3"/>
        </node>
    </highernode>
</root>
```

must become something like this:

```
    <root>
        <highernode>
            <highernodename>Name1</highernodename>
            <highernodeId>Id1</highernodeId>
                <somechild>1
                    <node>node1</node>
                    <node>node3</node>
                </somechild>
                <somechild>2
                    <node>node2</node>
                    <node>node4</node>
                </somechild>
                <somechild>3
                    <node>node5</node>
                </somechild>
        </highernode>

    <highernode>
        <highernodename>Name2</highernodename>
        <highernodeId>Id2</highernodeId>
            <somechild>1
                <node>node1</node>
            </somechild>
            <somechild>5
                <node>node2</node>
                <node>node3</node>
            </somechild>   
            <somechild>4
                <node>node6</node>
            </somechild> 
            <somechild>3
                <node>node5</node>
            </somechild>
    </highernode>
</root>
```

In other words, within each of the highernodes, I have to switch the attribute somechild with the node, keeping the order, then check if there are several somechild with the same value, and, in this case, group their former nodes under the same somechild.
After some reading on this topic: [Grouping XML nodes by attribute value in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7243965/grouping-xml-nodes-by-attribute-value-in-xslt)
It helped, but still, after adjusting it a bit to serve my own pourpose, I have some problems. My XSL looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="k" match="somechild" use="@child-id"/>
    <xsl:key name="n" match="node" use="somechild/@child-id"/>

    <xsl:template match="root/highernode">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="highernodename"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="highernodeId"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates 
                select="//somechild[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('k', @child-id))]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="somechild">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('n', @child-id)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template  match="node">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and the result is this:

```
    <highernode>
   <highernodename>Name1</highernodename>
   <highernodeId>Id1</highernodeId>
   <somechild>1<node>node1</node>
      <node>node3</node>
      <node>node1</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>2<node>node2</node>
      <node>node4</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>3<node>node5</node>
      <node>node5</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>5<node>node2</node>
      <node>node3</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>4<node>node6</node>
   </somechild>
</highernode>

    <highernode>
   <highernodename>Name2</highernodename>
   <highernodeId>Id2</highernodeId>
   <somechild>1<node>node1</node>
      <node>node3</node>
      <node>node1</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>2<node>node2</node>
      <node>node4</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>3<node>node5</node>
      <node>node5</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>5<node>node2</node>
      <node>node3</node>
   </somechild>
   <somechild>4<node>node6</node>
   </somechild>
</highernode>
```

As you can see, there are two issues:
1) in each of the highernodes, it brings the "somechild" and "node" from all the highernodes instead of the current node 
2) it orders "somechild" after its own value (see in the highernode2, somechild3 should be last, but it is not.

I hope I have been clear enough.

Thank you,
Mihai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to do Muenchian grouping like this within each node separately, you need to include something unique to the parent node in the key value that you use to group, for example:

```
<xsl:key name="k" match="somechild"
     use="concat(../../highernodeId, '|', @child-id)"/>
<xsl:key name="n" match="node"
     use="concat(../highernodeId, '|', somechild/@child-id)"/>
```

and the same when you dereference the key:

```
<xsl:template match="root/highernode">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="highernodename"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="highernodeId"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="node/somechild[generate-id(.) = generate-id(
              key('k', concat(current()/highernodeId, '|', @child-id)))]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="somechild">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('n',
                 concat(../../highernodeId, '|', @child-id))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Ian, that did the trick. I was kind of thinking that a unique criteria must be used for grouping, but did not know how to do it. Again, many thanks.